# rounding off oracle timestamp to integer

Tags: sql, oracle

```
INSERT INTO Calculations(TOTAL_DAYS_NUMBER) 
select DTE_CHARGE - (
   select min(TIME_REGISTERED)
   from (
      select TIME_REGISTERED from SHIFTING_RECORDS where id=5
      UNION ALL
      select TIME_REGISTERED from MEAL_RECORDS where id=5
      UNION ALL
      SELECT TIME_REGISTERED FROM REGISTRATION WHERE id=5
      )
   ) 
from REGISTRATION
where id=5;
```

**It gives me output  19 3:28:47.812000000** which is not possible for me to insert in a column having integer datatype, I am interested only in getting those first two digits i.e 19. How Shall I?

Comment: perhaps look up ceil, floor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `extract(DAY FROM ...)`:

```
INSERT INTO Calculations (TOTAL_DAYS_NUMBER)
SELECT extract(DAY FROM DTE_CHARGE - (
    SELECT min(TIME_REGISTERED) FROM (
        SELECT TIME_REGISTERED
        FROM SHIFTING_RECORDS
        WHERE id = 5

        UNION ALL

        SELECT TIME_REGISTERED
        FROM MEAL_RECORDS
        WHERE id = 5

        UNION ALL

        SELECT TIME_REGISTERED
        FROM REGISTRATION
        WHERE id = 5
    )
))
FROM REGISTRATION
WHERE id = 5;
```

Comment: Also, a minor point, but I don't think you need to use `UNION ALL`; just use `UNION` since you don't care about duplicates.

Comment: i think it speeds up the query execution time

Comment: UNION ALL is faster - it does not have to remove duplicates